# WP-Title filter not assigning variable

Tags: wordpress, php

I want to set term name as variable

```
if(isset($wp_taxonomies)) {
    $term = get_term_by(
        'slug', 
         get_query_var('term'), 
         get_query_var('taxonomy')
    );
    if($term) {
        // do stuff
    }
} 

function assignPageTitle(){     
    return $term>name;
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');
get_header();
```

This code is in the `taxonomy.php` file and the `$term>name;` returns the name, but only if I echo, on the title is giving me these errors:

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in **/home/jshomesc/public_html/wp-content/themes/jshomes/taxonomy.php** on line **12**
>
> Notice:  Undefined variable: term in **/home/jshomesc/public_html/wp-content/themes/jshomes/taxonomy.php** on line **12**

Comment: you need to change > to -> but then $term will still not be defined because it is not in scope.

Comment: Also please see [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. To access the term's `name` property, the syntax is like so `$term->name`.
2. The `assignPageTitle` function doesn't know about the global `$term` variable you've just retrieved above it.  It's trying to retrieve the `name` property of a local `$term` variable that hasn't been defined.

To fix it, add the `global` keyword (and check if it has been populated):

```
function assignPageTitle(){  

    // Now the function will know about the $term you've retrieved above  
    global $term;

    // Do we have a $term and name?
    if(isset($term, $term->name)){
        return $term->name;
    }
    return "No term for you...";
}
```

You can read more about PHP [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to help.